# Flappy bird pause

Tags: android, libgdx

i'm using Libgdx to create flappy bird game but don't know how to pause the game. when the game is paused, the bird fall down and the pipes moves till the bird is dead. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Here at SO we expect to see what you have tried and some code to help you out. This currently looks like you copy pasted code from a tutorial and don't have a clue what it does. And in that case it's impossible to really help you.

Answer (score 1):

Define gamepaused boolean variable. and set true when paused. 
Check all updates and changes with this variable.

```
if(!gamepaused)
{
draw.things
positions.update()
}
```

Or you can use different screen for pause menu.